# How can I completely return the array with nested array of objects inside if I am using spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I try to group the objects in an array, by their respective group number. I also added extra fields to tag objects if he/she is a leader or a member. That works, but my problem is, the 'advisers' objects inside my nested array were not returning. It is `null` when I uses spread syntax to return.

This is my array:

```
const data = [{
  "name": "John",
  "groupNo": 1
}, {
  "name": "Chelsea",
  "groupNo": 1
}, {
  "name": "Mark",
  "groupNo": 1
}, {
  "name": "Mary",
  "groupNo": 8
}, {
  advisers: [{
    "name": "Kenedy",
    "groupNo": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Chelsea",
    "groupNo": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Chris",
    "groupNo": 8
  }];
}];
```

This is my code for adding extra fields. It works but the `advisers` array is `null`.

```
const output = data.map(function(member) {
  if (this.has(member.groupNo)) {
    // Member
    return {
      ...member,
      "leaderNo": "",
      "memberNo": this.size
    }
  }
  // Leader
  this.add(member.groupNo)
  return {
    ...member,
    "leaderNo": this.size,
    "memberNo": ""
  }
}, new Set())

console.log(output);
```

I just want to retain all data in array including advisers array

Comment: What do you mean by "the 'advisers' objects inside my nested array were not returning". `{ ...{advisers: []} }` should not return `null`. Please share your full code. Running the code above does not return `null` in `advisers`

Comment: Yes exactly, it returns this way { ...{advisers: []} }  .. the code above is my full code

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: [
  {
    "name": "John",
    "groupNo": 1,
    "leaderNo": 1,
    "memberNo": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Chelsea",
    "groupNo": 1,
    "leaderNo": "",
    "memberNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark",
    "groupNo": 1,
    "leaderNo": "",
    "memberNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "groupNo": 8,
    "leaderNo": 4,
    "memberNo": ""
 }, {
  advisers: [{
    "name": "Kenedy",
    "groupNo": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Rob",
    "groupNo": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Chris",
    "groupNo": 8
  }];
}];

Comment: this is my expected output

Answer (score 1):

Your array is not consistent so you can add a check for the advisers key in the map function and go from there. Something like:

```
const {advisers} = member; 
if(advisers){
   return {advisers};
}
```